# Applying Bootstrap grid for inline elements

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a heading tag with a secondary subtitle like this:
[image]

```html
<h3>
  Fancy display heading
  <small class="text-muted">With faded secondary text</small>
</h3>
```

Is there a way to apply the Bootstrap grid system with column spacings for these inline elements, so that for small screens, the subtitle is on a different line?

[image]

I could only think to split the h1 into two columns and apply column classes to control the layout:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
    <h1>Fancy display heading</h1>
   </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
    <h1><small class="text-muted">With faded secondary text</small></h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

But there are now two heading tags and too much negative space between them.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I think you can add class "d-block" to your <small> tag. This will force is to take the whole line and hence will push it down.

Comment: @Alexander, yes adding d-block class does bring the subtitle to a new line. But I want to display the heading and the subtitle inline (side by side) for large screens and break them up into two only for small screens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest Bootstrap solution is to forget even using columns for this. Using [Bootstrap 4's display utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/display/) set the small element to display block by default, and for larger than small screens display inline like:

```
<h3>
  Fancy display heading
  <small class="d-block d-md-inline text-muted">With faded secondary text</small>
</h3>
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-VCmXjywReHh4PwowAiWNagnWcLhlEJLA5buUprzK8rxFgeH0kww/aWY76TfkUoSX" crossorigin="anonymous">
<h3>
  Fancy display heading
  <small class="d-block d-md-inline text-muted">With faded secondary text</small>
</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove h1 and add necessary css rules, because the browser makes margin for h1 by default

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 headingTest">
       Fancy display heading
   </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8 headingTest">
    <small class="text-muted">With faded secondary text</small>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.headingTest {
  font-size: 32px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify this using Bootstrap's CSS utilities with breakpoints. Let's say you want different behavior on medium screen sizes and up. To clarify, you want the following behavior:

Medium and up:

- The two headings should display inline with each other

Smaller than medium:

- The two headings should be one on top of the other

This is what the code would look like:

```
<h1 class="d-md-inline-block">Fancy display heading</h1>
<h2 class="d-md-inline-block text-muted">With faded secondary text</h2>
```

The utility class here means that the elements will be displayed inline-block for medium screen sizes and up.